# Lagging behind in levels, how do I catch up?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have been playing Torchlight 2 on "normal" difficulty using LAN multiplayer with a friend.  This is the first time we play and I'm not experienced with this type of games.

At the entrance of each quest there's an indication of what character level is recommended.  Until now this always matched my character level (more or less).

Somewhere in Act II we find ourselves with level 27 characters and only level 31 quests available.  It's proving too hard.  How can we level up our characters before tackling this quest?  All other side quests are finished, and I cannot find more monsters to kill.

Comment: First off you need to finish all the side quests that pop up, they are your extra experience source. Second, the gunslinger class is the best to clear the game with if you have experience in these types if not, the Engineer class is the best. Next would be exploring the map, you most likely went from point A to point B to finish the maps sooner rather than later, this results in less XP and tougher mobs since the game's scaling suddenly BOOMs up. However if you're an engineer most likely you'll be fine even if you're under leveled due to the tanking abilities and heals.

Comment: @Chessbrain Thanks for the advice!  I believe we finished all the side quests, at least we proceeded by exploring every corner of the map before moving on.

Comment: @Gabb If you can't find anything level appropriate to do just go backwards and find something level appropriate. Either you'll come across something you missed or you can just repeat a dungeon for some extra loot.

Comment: I finally used the "reroll world" option which recreated the monsters and gave the opportunity to level up.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it's fairly rare on "normal" difficulty to be too far behind the enemy level range to proceed. Here's what I normally do when playing through the game:

1. Explore each map fully. It's quite possible you missed some areas that have enemies or dungeons you didn't see.
2. Always complete the side quests in a given stage
3. Enter phase portal challenges when possible (go in prepared!)
4. If you stumble upon a dungeon that's too powerful for you at the moment, continue fully exploring the map. It's pretty easy to level up a few times on each map just by fully exploring it.
5. As a last resort, you can re-roll the world (as you did) and play through again.

Answer (score 2):

The most fun way is to replay your favorite dungeons.  Dungeons will re-spawn after 10 minutes if you enter another different dungeon.  Most dungeon bosses will re-spawn with the dungeon.

[Source](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=40118)